# Dynamic font size phonegap android app

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a question about the fontsize in a phonegap jquerymobile android app. My app is designed for xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi. I use mediaqueries in CSS. The questions:

- On XHDPI the jquerymobile header (and font) is real small. Do I need to specify a font size for the header? I thought jquerymobile handled the scalling based on the screen?

  `<div data-role="header">`
- Can I use the sp fontsize tag in CSS? This is not working:

  body{font-size:11sp;};
- Is there a standard to use in font-size? I.e. XHDPI: 14pt, HDPI: 12pt; ect...

Thanks!

Comment: you can do this `.ui-title { font-size: 11sp important; }`.

Comment: If I put that in my CSS file, notting changes.

Comment: Try using percentage `.ui-title { font-size: 150% important; }` note: this is for header and footer titles.

Comment: with the !important it is working, but still not exactly what i'm looking for. See my question above. Shouldn't Jquery handle this automatically?

Comment: With mediaqueries and `!important` it should work.

Comment: yes it is working, but "shouldn't Jquery handle this automatically?"

Comment: jQM media queries are based on screen size, i dont know about different resolutions.